# Dynamically disable jqgrid column

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, free-jqgrid

I want to disable few columns while editing but those columns will be enabled while adding through navGrid Add.
I am using below code:

```
  colModel: [
      { name: 'Menu_Key_Nm', index: 'Menu_Key_Nm', align: 'left', width: 200, sortable: false, editable: true, editrules: { required: true } },
      { name: 'Menu_Display_Nm', index: 'Menu_Display_Nm', align: 'left', width: 200, sortable: false, editable: true, editrules: { required: true } },
      { name: 'Category', index: 'Category', align: 'left', width: 200, sortable: false, editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { dataUrl: '@Url.Action("GetCategoryList", "Admin")'} },
  ]
```

In navGrid edit option I am writing the below code:

```
 //edit
 {
     beforeShowForm: function (form) {
        $("#tr_Menu_Key_Nm").attr("disabled", "true");
        $('#tr_Category').attr("disabled", "true");
      }
   url: '@Url.Action("Update")',
  closeAfterEdit: true
 },
 //Add option
 {
    beforeShowForm: function (form) {
        $("#tr_Menu_Key_Nm").attr("disabled", "false");
        $('#tr_Category').attr("disabled", "false");
      }
  }
```

But I am getting above columns disabled while adding after edit.
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image: while Adding through navGrid Add button]

Comment: @Oleg could you check it once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should fix the code and use `.prop("disabled", true)` or `.prop("disabled", false)` instead of `.attr("disabled", "true")` and `.attr("disabled", "false")`. If you use very old version of jQuery than you can use `attr`, but in the case the value should be `.attr("disabled", "disabled")` and `.removeAttr("disabled")`.

By the way I develop now new version of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) which you can already download and use. I plan release the version very soon. The version have many new features. One for the features is described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/editable-property-of-colModel-as-function). It allows you **to define `editable` property as function**. Inside of the function you can test whether `options.mode === "addForm"` and only in the case return true. In case of `options.mode === "editForm"` you can return "disabled" value which will do exactly the same what you do already in your code.

Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/disabledInAddForm.htm). It displays

[image]

and

[image]

The `editable` property of some columns are defined as `editable: editableInAddForm`, where the function `editableInAddForm` looks like below

```js
editableInAddForm = function (options) {
    if (options.mode === "addForm") {
        return true;
    }
    if (options.mode === "editForm") {
        return "disabled";
    }
    return false; // don't allows editing in other editing modes
}
```

Comment: Can I disable a column while viewing a selected row in the same way mentioned above?

Comment: I don't thought that it have sense, because no editing is allowed in View dialog. I can consider to allows to define `viewable` property as function in the same way like `editable`. I try to implement no more features in the current release of free jqGrid and only to fix bugs. Till the time you can use `beforeShowForm` callback of View options (the options of `viewGridRow`) and call `.prop("disabled", true)` for some fields.